# How do you create a new html element inside an embedded HTML document (HTML <object>)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used an `<object>` to embed a page within a page

```
<object data="http://www.w3.org/">
    this is where the elements of interest get rendered
</object>
```

I'm trying to get the HTML elements inside to do stuff. Let's say I want to `.hide()` an element there or insert a new one. How can one do that preferably with jQuery, if not with plain JavaScript?

jQuery selectors don't seem to find anything and `getElementById.contentDocument` doesn't work unless it's referred to a SVG.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rk57whzk/ should do something similar to what you want, but i don't get it to work...

Comment: @FloWin I fiddled with your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rk57whzk/1/ should be the updated version that workes on my local apache. Could be a problem jsfiddle.net's side

Comment: you can answer your question, if you want to

Comment: @FloWin I should have mentioned that the modifications to your fiddle were to make the html work, I'm having trouble on the Javascript-side. So i don't have an answer yet

Comment: sorry, i can't help you. i have tried everything i thought that could work. maybe it's just not possible, a bug, ...

Comment: It's unclear what you're ultimately trying to do, but if you're displaying an external web site (like w3.org) on your own web site, browser security restrictions prevent you from accessing its contents using client-side JS. You'd have to first pull the web site to your own server and display it from there.

Comment: @Juhana Yes that is true. After feverish research and tests done it seems that the only possible way to do this is to replace the `<object>` with an `<iframe>` and have it display a **local** replica of the webpage (`wget` was usefull in getting the local copy). Thank you for your feedback